# Send null value into stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

How to send null value for table value parameters to a stored procedure in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a null variable to a SQL Stored Procedure from C#.net code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207404/how-to-pass-a-null-variable-to-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-c-net-code)

Answer (score 5):

Use like this

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", DBNull.Value);
```

Here is a good link on the same topic
[How to pass a null variable to a SQL Stored Procedure from C#.net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207404/how-to-pass-a-null-variable-to-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-c-net-code)

You can go through link.
[Using DBNull.Value with SqlParameter without knowing sqlDbType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222819/using-dbnull-value-with-sqlparameter-without-knowing-sqldbtype)

Answer (score 3):

There is an little issue using DBNull.Value though. Lets say i have a bit in the store procedure named IO.

in the store procedure

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Check]
   @IO BIT
```

Then at the code I add the parameter as follows.

```
   object parameter = new SqlParameter("IO", true); //using false is the same.
```

And then I call the store procedure

```
   _repositary.DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<CallDetail>("exec stp_Check @IO", parameter)();
```

Here _repository is my DataRepository class with context. Knowing that it'll execute the sp is enough for this.

You can catch the call using sql server profiler. That will be generated as follows.

```
declare @p24 int
set @p24=7
exec sp_executesql N'exec stp_Check @IO', --parameter passed
N'@IO bit', -- parameter with the type passed
@IO=1 --parameter value used when executing the sp
select @p24
```

The problem is this. When you create the parameter with DBNull.Value as follows.

```
    object parameter = new SqlParameter("IO", (object)DBNull.Value);
```

From the sql server profiler what you can find out is

```
declare @p24 int
set @p24=7
exec sp_executesql N'exec stp_Check @IO', --parameter passed
N'@IO nvarchar(4000)', -- the passes type is not boolean
@IO=NULL --parameter value is NULL
select @p24
```

True that this will work.But this is not what is intended. I prefer

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

You can pass null as follows.

```
 object parameter = new SqlParameter("IO", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean.Null );
```

Then the request is like this.

```
declare @p24 int
set @p24=7
exec sp_executesql N'exec stp_Check @IO', --parameter passed
N'@IO bit', -- the passes type is boolean
@IO=NULL --parameter value is NULL
select @p24
```

There are null values for all sqltypes such as int, bigint, datetime etc. Hope this help. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DBNull.Value` to pass `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add null as default paramter value and dont send any value if you want it to be null

ex:

```
create procedure sp_name(@param1 varhcra(10), @param2 varchar(10)=null)
```

C#

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "value1");
//dont pass any value for param2, it is considered null
```

Comment: **Do not** use the `sp_` prefix for your own stored procedures! That prefix is **reserved by Microsoft** for their own use.