# Null value in a parameter varbinary datatype

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, parameters, dbnull

How can I add a null value in a parameter varbinary datatype?

When I execute the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection1 = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(EmpName, Image) Values(@EmpName, @Image)", myDatabaseConnection1))
    {
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", textBoxEmpName.Text);
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", DBNull.Value);
        myDatabaseConnection1.Open();
        mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I get the following `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: I have a little detection strategy for dealing with null instances of `byte[]` cast as `object` on a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42905940/97964

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
cmd.Parameters.Add( "@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1 );

cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks. What is -1 for?

Comment: It is the length and SqlDbType.VarBinary with length -1 is the equivalent of VARBINARY(MAX), at least in theory. ;)

Comment: How did you know that the datatype lenght is MAX?

Comment: I dont know...I just assumed!! ;)

Comment: Parameters.Add is deprecated, any better idea?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding Use Parameters.AddWithValue

Answer (score 16):

I dont know the reason why "DBNull.Value" does not work for me.
And I figure out another solution can solve this problem.

```
cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
```

Comment: This worked for me and fit in with the helper method that was previously sending DBNull.Value if the byte[] value was null.

Comment: 4 years later and -- This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: `SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null` for the win. Thank you, kind individual. Take my upvote.

Answer (score 7):

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", SqlBinary.Null);
```

Comment: While this answer may answer the question adding some more detail like why and how this works will improve its quality

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", new byte[]{});
```

Comment: `Parameters.Add` is deprecated, this answer maybe better, only thing to be noticed is that, it will not insert a `NULL` data (in the table you see the word `NULL`) but an `EMPTY` data (in the table you will see nothing)

Comment: This is the best solution as stated by Ronaldinho, thanks for the answer Shamseer

Comment: As @RonaldinhoLearnCoding said, it's important to note that `byte[0]` is not the same as `null`.

Answer (score 1):

i do it like this without a problem

```
SqlParameter image= new SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, System.DBNull.Value);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(image);
```

Comment: but Parameters.Add is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Set null value in your Stored Procedure. Doesn't need to do anything else.

```
ex. @photo varbinary(max) = null,

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOurTeam]
    @name nvarchar(50),
    @Sname nvarchar(50),
    @designation nvarchar(50),
    @photo varbinary(max) = null,
    @Pname nvarchar(50)=null,
    @psize bigint=null,
    @id int output
    AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        insert into OurTeam values (@name,@Sname,@designation,@photo,@Pname,@psize);

        select @id= SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Comment: Solved my problem ;)